Iterate a function over a list of dataframes
I have 2 timeframes, for example 15 minutes and 4 hours, and want to calculate volume ma on them. I wrote a function for it, now I want to use a for loop for this purpose. But I have faced some errors.
The function:
def volume_ma(timeframe=M15, length=20):
    timeframe['volume_ma'] = ta.sma(timeframe['tick_volume'], length=length)

volume_ma()

Loop:
dataframes = {'M1': M1, 'H4': H4}

for name, sublist in dataframes.items():
    volume_ma(name)


Ok,sorry it solved
for name,sublist in dataframes.items():
    volume_ma(timeframe=sublist)

and another solution is not using dictionaries. It can be solved just by using a simple list of dataframes like this:
dataframes = [M1,H4] 
for dataframe in dataframes:
   volume_ma(dataframe= dataframe)

